# Windows 10 Update to 2004 failure - Error: 0x80004005 - 0x60016

Tags: windows-10, bootloader, mbr, bcd

I've been trying for the last week or so to get Windows 10  to update to 2004. I've tried all of the common solutions (sfc /scannow, DISM restore, media creation tool etc).

After looking at the log files I think I've narrowed the issue to a BCD/MBR issue (see full logs below). In the SetupDiag you can see the part which has failed is in the `Finalize` phase and `Update Boot Code` operation. Looking in the `setuperr.log` there's a point at which this error occurs:

```
IBSLIB BCD: BcdCopyObjectEx: Failed to create object. Target: {a5a30fa2-3d06-4e9f-b5f4-a01ff9d1fcba} Flags: 0x1  Status: c00000bb[gle=0x00000002]
IBSLIB BCD: Failed to clone store. Status: c00000bb[gle=0x00000002]
IBSLIB BCD: BcdExportStore: Failed clone BCD to \??\C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD. Status: c00000bb[gle=0x00000002]
```

This led me down the path of trying to rebuild the BCD.

I've tried various guides but all of them seem to fall over at the stage of doing `bootrec /fixboot` due to an `Access denied` error or when I try to use `bcdedit /export` I get an `The store export operation has failed.`

Can anyone advise if I'm even heading in the right direction by looking into the BCD? If so, any suggestions on how to fix it?

If not, what else can I try to fix this error? Unfortunately, I also had it with the last Windows 10 feature update and I'm trying not to resort back to a clean install.

**Update:**
I've noticed something odd which may be nothing. I tried following another guide to rebuild the BCR which also dealt with the `Access denied` error ([link here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/faq/how-to-repair-efi-bootloader-in-windows-10.3275168/)). This worked, but I noticed that when I looked at my drives (`diskpart list vol`) when using the bootable media and when I'm loaded into Windows, my two SSDs are swapped letters.

So this is booted to Windows:

```
Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     D   SSD2         NTFS   Partition    232 GB  Healthy
Volume 1     C   SSD          NTFS   Partition    111 GB  Healthy    Boot
Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition     99 MB  Healthy    System
Volume 3     E   HDD          NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy
Volume 4     G   ESD-USB      FAT32  Removable     15 GB  Healthy
```

And just for clarity, this is Disk Management's view of the system:

[image: disk management]

However, this is the same thing when booted via the bootable media USB:

```
Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     C   SSD2         NTFS   Partition    232 GB  Healthy
Volume 1     D   SSD          NTFS   Partition    111 GB  Healthy    Boot
Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition     99 MB  Healthy    System
Volume 3     E   HDD          NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy
Volume 4     F   ESD-USB      FAT32  Removable     15 GB  Healthy
```

Note the `C` and `D` drives are swapped and the USB (`ESD-USB`) is assigned letter `F`.

When looking at the error logs, line `Failed to backup BCD database from "F:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD" to "C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD".[gle=0x00000032]` stands out.

I wonder if for some reason it's trying to set the Rollback Checkpoint on the wrong drive? It's seems unlikely but tomorrow I might try doing the update with all other non-C drives unplugged just to see if that works, but I'm not hopeful.

**Update 2:**
As expected, running the update with only the C drive plugged in didn't work either. Exactly the same issue. I've updated the log files.

**LOG FILES**

SetupDiagResults.log:

```
Matching Profile found: FindAbruptDownlevelFailure - 55882B1A-DA3E-408A-9076-23B22A0472BD
SetupDiag version: 1.6.0.0
System Information:
    Machine Name = DESKTOP-NQP82FD
    Manufacturer = System manufacturer
    Model = System Product Name
    HostOSArchitecture = 2057
    FirmwareType = UEFI
    BiosReleaseDate = 20191209000000.000000+000
    BiosVendor = 3003
    BiosVersion = 3003
    HostOSVersion = 10.0.18363
    HostOSBuildString = 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.19041.1 (vb_release.191206-1406)
    HostOSLanguageId = 
    HostOSEdition = Core
    RegisteredAV = Windows Defender
    FilterDrivers = FileInfo
    UpgradeStartTime = 27/07/2020 17:51:14
    UpgradeEndTime = 27/07/2020 18:18:45
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 00:27:31
    CV = 
    ReportId = 

Error: SetupDiag reports abrupt down-level failure.
Last Operation: Finalize
Error: 0x80004005 - 0x50016
LogEntry: 2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 SP     Operation failed: Update Boot Code. Error: 0x80004005[gle=0x000000b7]

Refer to "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes" for error information.

Last Setup Phase:
Phase Name: Finalize
    Phase Started: 27/07/2020 18:16:55
    Phase Ended: 01/01/0001 00:00:00
    Phase Time Delta: 00:00:00
    Completed Successfully? False


Last Setup Operation:
Operation Name: Update Boot Code
    Operation Started: 27/07/2020 18:16:59
    Operation Ended: 01/01/0001 00:00:00
    Operation Time Delta: 0:00:00:00.0000000
    Completed Successfully? False
```

setuperr.log output:

```
2020-07-27 18:15:12, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\NewOS\Windows\system32\migration\scmdmigplugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7f.[gle=0x0000007f]
2020-07-27 18:15:12, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007f.[gle=0x0000007f]
2020-07-27 18:15:12, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\NewOS\Windows\system32\migration\scmdmigplugin.dll, {D7A91520-AAFC-416F-9D7B-2C2E933BCAA7}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007f].
2020-07-27 18:15:12, Error      [0x08038d] MIG    Failure while calling IPostApply->ApplySuccess for Plugin={ServerPath="%SYSTEM32%\migration\scmdmigplugin.dll", CLSID={D7A91520-AAFC-416F-9D7B-2C2E933BCAA7}, ThreadingModel=Apartment}. Error: 0x8007007F
2020-07-27 18:15:12, Error                 SP     Error READ, 0x0000007F while gathering/applying object: apply-success, Action,CMXEPlugin,C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Work\MachineSpecific\Working\agentmgr\CCSIAgent,%SYSTEM32%\migration\scmdmigplugin.dll,{D7A91520-AAFC-416F-9D7B-2C2E933BCAA7},Apartment. Will return 2[gle=0x000000cb]
2020-07-27 18:15:12, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: ParseRegistryIfBridgeExists: offline key (new) = '$OFFLINE_RW_BCE441CA$SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\Bridge'
2020-07-27 18:15:12, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: ParseRegistryIfBridgeExists: query bridge presence key failed 0x139f, bridge present = 0
2020-07-27 18:15:13, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\schemacachehelpers.cpp(607)\shmig.dll!00007FFA004573BE: (caller: 00007FFA00455315) ReturnHr(1) tid(22f4) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Migrated key for Path $OFFLINE_RW_BCE441CA$SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertySchema.Migrated for 32-bit hive not found ] 

2020-07-27 18:15:13, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\schemacachehelpers.cpp(607)\shmig.dll!00007FFA004573BE: (caller: 00007FFA00455348) ReturnHr(2) tid(22f4) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Migrated key for Path $OFFLINE_RW_BCE441CA$SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertySchema.Migrated for 64-bit hive not found ] 

2020-07-27 18:15:14, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!RemoveObsoleteCHSHKLMRegkey - fail to open regkey (software\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{E429B25A-E5D3-4D1F-9BE3-0C608477E3A1}\LanguageProfile\0x00000804) = 2
2020-07-27 18:15:14, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!ApplySuccess() remove HKLM Registries error
2020-07-27 18:15:14, Error      [0x08038d] MIG    Failure while calling IPostApply->ApplySuccess for Plugin={ServerPath="Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client\adammigrate.dll", CLSID={43CCF250-2A74-48c6-9620-FC312EC475D6}, ThreadingModel=Apartment}. Error: 0x80070002
2020-07-27 18:15:14, Error                 SP     Error READ, 0x00000002 while gathering/applying object: apply-success, Action,CMXEPlugin,C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests,Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client\adammigrate.dll,{43CCF250-2A74-48c6-9620-FC312EC475D6},Apartment. Will return 2[gle=0x000000cb]
2020-07-27 18:15:14, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext: LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\NewOS\Windows\system32\migration\scmdmigplugin.dll, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7f.[gle=0x0000007f]
2020-07-27 18:15:14, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost: CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc: LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed hr=0x8007007f.[gle=0x0000007f]
2020-07-27 18:15:14, Error      [0x0808ff] MIG    COutOfProcPluginFactory::CreateInstance: m_currentHostSurrogate->LoadDllServer(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\NewOS\Windows\system32\migration\scmdmigplugin.dll, {D7A91520-AAFC-416F-9D7B-2C2E933BCAA7}, 0) failed, hr=[0x8007007f].
2020-07-27 18:15:14, Error      [0x080390] MIG    Failure while calling IPostApply->PostApply for Plugin={ServerPath="%SYSTEM32%\migration\scmdmigplugin.dll", CLSID={D7A91520-AAFC-416F-9D7B-2C2E933BCAA7}, ThreadingModel=Apartment}. Error: 0x8007007F
2020-07-27 18:15:14, Error                 SP     Error READ, 0x0000007F while gathering/applying object: post-apply, Action,CMXEPlugin,C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Work\MachineSpecific\Working\agentmgr\CCSIAgent,%SYSTEM32%\migration\scmdmigplugin.dll,{D7A91520-AAFC-416F-9D7B-2C2E933BCAA7},Apartment. Will return 2[gle=0x000000cb]
2020-07-27 18:15:18, Error                 MIG    Ignoring replacement manifest with no settingsVersionRange or versionRange attribute in migration element: Microsoft-Windows-Container-Manager
2020-07-27 18:15:21, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: "script" attribute is mandatory. class Mig::CMXEMerge *__cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::LoadMerge(class UnBCL::XmlNode *,int,class Mig::CMXEMigrationXml *,class Mig::CMXEXmlComponent *)
2020-07-27 18:15:22, Error      [0x0803eb] MIG    Error: 161 Message: Error opening the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC: The specified path is invalid. [0x000000A1][gle=0x00000002]
2020-07-27 18:15:22, Error      [0x0803eb] MIG    Error: 161 Message: Error opening the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TabletPC: The specified path is invalid. [0x000000A1][gle=0x00000002]
2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2[gle=0x00000012]
2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2[gle=0x00000002]
2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2[gle=0x00000012]
2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-ErrorReportingCore[@version="10.0.18362.959" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-ErrorReportingCore[@version="10.0.18362.959" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\UserChoiceHelpers.h(808)\shmig.dll!00007FF9FFF2B8D1: (caller: 00007FF9FFF2BFD0) LogHr(1) tid(231c) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.

2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\UserChoiceHelpers.h(809)\shmig.dll!00007FF9FFF2B90B: (caller: 00007FF9FFF2BFD0) LogHr(2) tid(231c) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.

2020-07-27 18:15:24, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\UserChoiceHelpers.h(810)\shmig.dll!00007FF9FFF2B935: (caller: 00007FF9FFF2BFD0) LogHr(3) tid(231c) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.

2020-07-27 18:15:27, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:27, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:27, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:27, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:32, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:32, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:42, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-ErrorReportingCore[@version="10.0.18362.959" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:42, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-ErrorReportingCore[@version="10.0.18362.959" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="perUser"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:42, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {050ed09e-a530-41e6-8ac9-a9a96e74a2c1}: [shmig] onecoreuap\internal\shell\inc\private\UserChoiceHelpers.h(810)\shmig.dll!00007FFA07A2B935: (caller: 00007FFA07A2BFD0) LogHr(1) tid(1830) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.

2020-07-27 18:15:44, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2[gle=0x00000012]
2020-07-27 18:15:44, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:44, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [CEIPEnabled]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:45, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:45, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:45, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [EnableForcedLogoff]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:45, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [EnableSecuritySignature]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:45, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [ImagePath]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:45, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [RequireSecuritySignature]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:45, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SMBServer[@version="10.0.18362.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [RestrictNullSessAccess]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [EnableControl]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [ICSDomain]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [ScopeAddress]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [ScopeAddressBackup]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [SharedAutoDial]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [EnableControl]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [ICSDomain]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [ScopeAddress]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [ScopeAddressBackup]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:47, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-SharedAccess[@version="10.0.18362.778" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [SharedAutoDial]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:50, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-ErrorReportingCore[@version="10.0.18362.959" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:50, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-ErrorReportingCore[@version="10.0.18362.959" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:50, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-ErrorReportingCore[@version="10.0.18362.959" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [DefaultConsent]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:50, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-ErrorReportingCore[@version="10.0.18362.959" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [DisableWER]. Will return 2
2020-07-27 18:15:51, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!RemoveObsoleteCHSHKLMRegkey - fail to open regkey (software\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{E429B25A-E5D3-4D1F-9BE3-0C608477E3A1}\LanguageProfile\0x00000804) = 2
2020-07-27 18:15:51, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!ApplySuccess() remove HKLM Registries error
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 IBSLIB BCD: BcdCopyObjectEx: Failed to create object. Target: {a5a30fa2-3d06-4e9f-b5f4-a01ff9d1fcba} Flags: 0x1  Status: c00000bb[gle=0x00000002]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 IBSLIB BCD: Failed to clone store. Status: c00000bb[gle=0x00000002]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 IBSLIB BCD: BcdExportStore: Failed clone BCD to \??\C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD. Status: c00000bb[gle=0x00000002]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 IBSLIB OSRollbackService::CBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint::Finalize: Failed to backup BCD database from "D:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD" to "C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD".[gle=0x00000032]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error      [0x064199] IBSLIB SetCheckpoint(WinPEBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint): threw exception.: class RollbackException: RollbackException: Error(50), CSystemVolumeSelectionCheckpoint: Failed to backup BCD database. void __cdecl OSRollbackService::CBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint::Finalize(const unsigned short *,struct OSRollbackService::ICheckpointParameters *)[gle=0x00000032]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error      [0x06418a] IBSLIB RollbackSetCheckpoint(WinPEBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint): threw exception.: class RollbackException: RollbackException: Error(50), CSystemVolumeSelectionCheckpoint: Failed to backup BCD database. void __cdecl OSRollbackService::CCheckpointImpressario::SetCheckpoint(const unsigned short *,struct OSRollbackService::ICheckpointParameters *)
void __cdecl OSRollbackService::CBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint::Finalize(const unsigned short *,struct OSRollbackService::ICheckpointParameters *)[gle=0x00000032]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error      [0x06414e] IBSLIB RollbackSetCheckpoint(WinPEBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint) failed. Disabling Rollback.[gle=0x00000032]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 SP     Error setting OS Switch Rollback checkpoint[gle=0x00000032]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 IBSLIB BCD: BcdCopyObjectEx: Failed to create object. Target: {a5a30fa2-3d06-4e9f-b5f4-a01ff9d1fcba} Flags: 0x1  Status: c00000bb[gle=0x00000002]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 IBSLIB BCD: Failed to clone store. Status: c00000bb[gle=0x00000002]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 IBSLIB BCD: BcdExportStore: Failed clone BCD to \??\C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD. Status: c00000bb[gle=0x00000002]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 IBSLIB OSRollbackService::CBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint::Finalize: Failed to backup BCD database from "D:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD" to "C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD".[gle=0x00000032]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error      [0x064199] IBSLIB SetCheckpoint(WinPEBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint): threw exception.: class RollbackException: RollbackException: Error(50), CSystemVolumeSelectionCheckpoint: Failed to backup BCD database. void __cdecl OSRollbackService::CBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint::Finalize(const unsigned short *,struct OSRollbackService::ICheckpointParameters *)[gle=0x00000032]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error      [0x06418a] IBSLIB RollbackSetCheckpoint(WinPEBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint): threw exception.: class RollbackException: RollbackException: Error(50), CSystemVolumeSelectionCheckpoint: Failed to backup BCD database. void __cdecl OSRollbackService::CCheckpointImpressario::SetCheckpoint(const unsigned short *,struct OSRollbackService::ICheckpointParameters *)
void __cdecl OSRollbackService::CBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint::Finalize(const unsigned short *,struct OSRollbackService::ICheckpointParameters *)[gle=0x00000032]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error      [0x06414e] IBSLIB RollbackSetCheckpoint(WinPEBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint) failed. Disabling Rollback.[gle=0x00000032]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 SP     Error setting OS Switch Rollback checkpoint[gle=0x00000032]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 SP     Operation failed: Update Boot Code. Error: 0x80004005[gle=0x000000b7]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 SP     ExecuteOperations: Failed execution phase Finalize. Error: 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Finalize reported failure!
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Using action error code: [0x80004005]
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionFinalize::ExecuteSetupPlatformFinalize(1120): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:16:59, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionFinalize::ExecuteRoutine(510): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:17:00, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Execute(493): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:17:00, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteAction(3300): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:17:00, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteActions(3454): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:17:00, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Execute(1631): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:17:00, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2630): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:17:00, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2593): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:17:00, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(944): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:17:00, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(410): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:17:04, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(295): Result = 0x80004005
2020-07-27 18:17:04, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(433): Result = 0x80004005
```

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 is currently installed? Are you using Windows Update to upgrade, and if not where did you get the media?

Comment: Currently on `1909, build 18363.959`. I've tried using both Windows Update (which is where it originally failed) and then in attempting to fix it, I've created 2004 installation media from the Microsoft website (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10). It also fails to do the update from that and also fails with Start-up repair (logs suggest it finds no issues).

Comment: Why are you not installing 2004 through Windows Update.  Do you have a device that is blocking the update.?

Comment: Seems there is some weird mix-up of disks. Your suggested experiment of disconnecting all disks but C: might throw some light here. Disconnect also all external disks, and if installing from Windows then boot into Safe mode.

Comment: @Ramhound I did try it through Windows Update. As I said: that's where it originally failed. Windows Update tried to install 2004 and failed. I don't believe it's a device or driver issue as those typically have specific error codes and there's no indication of that in the log files.

Comment: @harrymc I'll report back when I try it later this evening.

Comment: As expected, trying to do the update with only the C drive installed didn't work. Same error with `Operation failed: Update Boot Code. Error: 0x80004005`. The log files still show the various BCD errors. I'm completely out of ideas now...

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue with Windows 10 22H2 upgrade-install (on top of almost-normally-working Windows 10 22H2).
I managed to fix this by recreating the BCD from scratch:

1. Back up entire HDD(s) you plan to modify (e.g. with [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/), savedisk, dd-only).
2. Run `bcdedit` and take a note which partitions currently have BCD-related files.

   - Alternatively, try [Visual BCD editor](https://www.boyans.net/) or [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)
3. From Windows Recovery cmd, format the partition with the `bootmgr` (which is usually a separate small partition).

   - Note suspicious `Boot` folders on the other disks. Consider removing and recreating them later, if removing/recreating just the `bootmgr` would not be enough.
4. Recreate the BCD with `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bcdboot C:\Windows /s S:`, `bootrec /rebuildbcd`.
5. Verify that `bcdedit /export C:\temp\bcd.bin.tmp` now works OK.
6. Proceed with upgrading Windows.